# How to dump android meminfo into a file?

Tags: android, memory, dump

I'm taking a detailed look into the resources of my apps. Unfortunatly when I execute the `adb shell dumpsys meminfo`, it overflows my terminal. Anyone know how I can instead of viewing the dump in terminal, have it print into a file so I can pull and view it in a text editor?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Redirect the output - `adb shell dumpsys meminfo > meminfo.txt`

Comment: Thanks. Where is the file stored so I can pull it?

Comment: it is saved in the same directory where you run the command from

Comment: Ah, thanks. I though it would have been stored on the phone. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Redirect it using `>` operator:

```
adb shell dumpsys meminfo >meminfo.txt
```

Alternatively, you can pipe it directly to a viewer such as `less`:

```
adb shell dumpsys meminfo | less
```

Comment: It's in your current directory. Of course you can change that, e.g. `>~/meminfo.txt` will store it in your home directory.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to redirecting, you can just pipe it through more:

```
adb shell dumpsys meminfo | more
```

Then you can just page through the output.

Or, honestly, make your terminal buffer larger so you can scroll back through it.  Having a terminal where you can't even scroll back through the output of this command seems pretty ghastly. :)

Answer (score 0):

use dumpsys -l and check if power option is there. Its not possible that no power state is maintained.

either you dont have write permission in the directory you are trying to create on device.
better use adb shell dumpsys power and it comes out to your pc rather than on device memory